# Not sharing configuration files from a Parent Project

Tags: maven, module, lifecycle

I have a parent pom looking like this:

```
...
<module>mod1</module>
...

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          ...
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          ...
        </plugin>
      </plugin>
    </build>
```

with two plugins,maven-resources-plugin and maven-antrun-plugin.

I want those plugins executed only within the parent pom.
But my problem is that they are executed in my module too.

Even so I'm not using pluginManagment tag.

I'm lost, i don't understand... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `inherited` to `false`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      ...
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      ...
    </plugin>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

See also: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Plugins